# Pause and Resume a Python Script from failed step

Tags: python, redis, robotframework

I have a long running python script(let's call it `upgrade.py`).
The script has many steps or parts (essentially XML API calls to a router to run certain commands on the router).

I need suggestions on how to achieve the following:
I'm looking to compartmentalize the script such that if any step fails the script execution should pause and it notifies the user via email (I can handle the emailing part).

The user can then fix the issue on his router and should be able to RESUME his script i.e. script resumes execution starting from the step that failed.

In short how do I go about compartmentalizing the script into steps (or test cases) so that:

1. The script PAUSES at a certain step that failed
2. The user is able to later RESUME the script (starting from that failed step)

Answer (score 0):

Most test automation approaches will break off the test suite and then re-try all test cases after a fix has been applied. This has the added benefit that when a fix impacts already run scripts, this is also discovered.

Given the lengthy nature of your test, this may not be practical. The below scipt will use the `Dialogs` and the `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds` to allow for 3 retries before continuing with the next step in the test case.

```
*** Settings ***                
Library Dialogs

*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  3 times    1 second  Failing Keyword
    Log To Console    End Test Case    

*** Keywords ***
Failing Keyword
    Fail    Keyword failed
    [Teardown]    Dialogs.Pause Execution    Please Check your settings.
```